# How to track deep changes in computed object with watcher

Tags: vue.js

I seem to be having difficulty in tracking deep changes in a computed object inside a component.

I have a computed schedule object defined as:

```
    computed: {
        schedule() { // return the current schedule object
            return this.$store.getters['schedules/getScheduleByName'](this.picked)
        }
    },
```

I define a watch:

```
    watch: {
        schedule: {
            handler() {
                this.activeColor = 'blue' // this is stored in the data function
            },
            deep: true,
        },
    },
```

And this does indeed track the changes.  However, because the scheduler object seems to change as the component loads the color change happens straight away rather than after I have manually changed the object properties.  Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve the effect of the color initially being red and then changing AFTER the component has fully initialised?

Thank you in advance,

Martyn

Comment: Why not putting it in a method an call in in the mounted() hook?

Comment: Thanks, do you mean setting the color on the mounted hook? I tried to do that but it was still overridden and the color was blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to keep a flag in your data, set it when you manually change the schedule. then in your watch, check if the flag is set before changing color.

Comment: Hi, I ended up adding a counter in the data that is incremented on a change.  As it loads the counter increments to 1 and no chnages are applied to the style any subsequent changes means counter > 1 and style changes happen.  I could not work out how to set the flag so that it did not change when the automatic chnage happened on the page load.

Comment: @MartynW That is a good way to handle it too. Glad to know your problem is solved ^_^